# Drools DRL variable instantiation when using OR

Tags: drools

I have the following rule condition

```
$entity: (Entity(field != null) or Entity(field == null))
```

If the drools session has these two facts

1. `Entity(field = null)`
2. `Entity(field = "Some Value")`

When I inspect `$entity`, which of the two is going to be there?
The behavior I'm looking for is for `$entity` to store `Entity(field = "Some value")` if both facts are in session, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The behavior I'm looking for is for `$entity` to store `Entity(field = "Some value")` if both facts are in session, is there a way to accomplish this?

You'd do this by checking for both and then only keeping the one that you really want to be doing work on.

```
rule "Example"
when
  exists( Entity(field == null ) )
  $entity: Entity( field != null )
then
  // ...
end
```

Here, the rule checks for the presence of an `Entity` that has no field value set using the `exists` operator. Exists, like it implies, only checks that a fact meets these criteria, but doesn't ever retain a reference to it.

Then the second condition checks that an `Entity` exists that does have a field value set, and assigns it to `$entity` so it can be referenced in the consequences/right hand side/then clause.

Only if both of these conditions are met will this rule trigger.

---

Note that if you happen to have three facts in working memory like this:

- A: `Entity(field = null)`
- B: `Entity(field = "ABC" )`
- C: `Entity(field = "XYZ")`

... then this rule will fire twice. It will trigger once for A+B and once for A+C. In both cases, the presence of fact A will satisfy the `exists` condition, but both B and C satisfy the second condition so will both independently trigger the rule.

Comment: Great, I can see that. But what if I need to store in $entity, the Entity(field==null) if there is no Entity(field != null)? is that possible? 

Like whenever there is an Entity(field != null) stored it, but when there is not, store Entity(field==null), the thing is that I need to do this on the same variable, to use later on the condition

Comment: Different rules. You can test for lack of presence with `not( Entity( field == null))`. (`not` works the same as `exists` but checks the opposite condition.)

Comment: You're right, I had to split this on two different rules, thanks for the help. By change do you know where I can find explicitly how does the engine is matching the facts against the rules? I'm a little bit confuse about the strategy that is used for this and think that's why some of my rules are not working as expected. I tried to see some docs, but I couldn't find much about this.

Comment: It's rather complicated, really. If you write a listener and attach it to your session, you can put break points in it and explore what it's doing. But it's much more complicated than I could explain in a comment. :)